# crack above door

Tags: doors, crack

I am a new home owner and just noticing this.  Is this a crack that the previous owner has tried to fix (It is a 1965 built home)

[image]

Also, I notice the sliding door is not closing fully at this location.  I see the door touches the trim at the bottom but at the top side it doesn't engage completely.  Should I re-do the drywall on top of this location?

[image]

Comment: Technically that's a "pocket door."

Comment: That is probably just a common settling crack.  The door is different and might just need adjustment of the rollers.  Might need measurement of door frame for plumb/level/straightness if roller adjustment does not fix.

Comment: Thanks all.. I am learning a lot :-)  The crack had me really worried.. I will leave it as it is for now

Comment: If that's the worst you have in a 1965 house (almost 60 years old), you're doing pretty well with a solid house.  If it were me, I wouldn't worry about the crack until I go to repaint, then just repair as indicated in a previous comment.  Though I'm curious why there's an outlet at light-switch level to the right of the door, as that's an uncommon height for an outlet if there isn't a cabinet underneath it.

Comment: yes, there is no cabinet under the outlet.. not sure why it was there :-)